# CLion + cygwin = dll

Tags: c++, windows, dll, cmake, clion

Народ, подскажите как под виндой собрать свою dll на clion + cygwin, а то я что-то забугорные сайты копаю уже второй час, а найти не могу. Как прилинковать к своему проекту нашел, а как самому библиотеку скомпилить - нет. Может там файлы cpp и h надо оформлять по особому или CMakeLists.txt чего вписать конкретного нужно? А то по умолчанию он мне тупо exe собирает.

Comment: выложите пример вашего кода, укажите, где, по вашему мнению, ошибка. это ускорит помощь

Comment: Я создаю просто новый проект и в нем есть два файла из примера https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms235636.aspx

Comment: https://cmake.org/Wiki/BuildingWinDLL

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо всем за помощь, я просто впервые столкнулся с cmake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Кажется разобрался, чтобы создать dll, нужно прописать в CMakeLists.txt
**add_library(<имя_приложения> SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})** вместо **add_executable(<имя_приложения> ${SOURCE_FILES})**